# Make a light box appear out of an iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

Here is my website:

http://cascadestudios.webstarts.com/index.html

Once you're there click on the button (on the right) called **"Mass Layouts"**

If you click on one of those pictures, It will open a lightbox **INSIDE** the iframe box.

How would I make it so that when I click on those pictures the lightbox appears **OUTSIDE** the iframe and appears on top of the whole website? I hope that makes sense.

Is this possible to do? Would I have to get rid of the iframe and have a div box?

Comment: Please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005464/how-to-make-a-lightbox-breakout-of-an-iframe and this page for the demo: http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html

Answer (score 0):

I thnis that you need this, try this lightbox: 
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/